# Чи існує в українській мові конструкція «я вибачаюсь»?

Tags: вживання-слів

У рекламному відділі однієї з районних газет: «Я вибачаюсь, а можна ще подати оголошення?»

[У Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA&oldid=22189987) (станом на 2018-03-21; посилання і закреслення в цитаті відтворюють оригінальне форматування Вікіпедії):

> «[вибачатись](http://chak-chy-pravylno-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/v#vybachyty)» — розмовний стиль; <s>не варто вибачати самого себе (але «він вибачився переді мною» — правильно)</s>
>   Вибачатися — просити вибачення, усвідомлюючи свою провину. «Дуже вибачаюсь, що самому ніколи забігти до Вас», Панас Мирний<sup>[[3]](http://sum.in.ua/?swrd=%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F)</sup>.

То як бути?

Answer (score 5):

Але є й інша позиція. Я зазначаю її окремо, тому що, по-перше, я знайшов її вже після написання [основної відповіді](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3405) (яка здавалася мені нейтральною), а по-друге, вона трішки відбивається від позиції інших мовознавців.

Святослав Караванський вважав обмеження на використання «я вибачаюся» штучними, нехарактерними власне українській мові, а можливо, притягнутими з російської (в якій форма «я извиняюсь», активно засуджувана російськими пуристами, на його думку, якраз і пішла від українського «я вибачаюся»).

> Один з поширених в Україні на найвищому мовознавчому рівні забобонів є табу на вживання в українській мові слова вибачатись, зокрема виразу я вибачаюсь.
>
> Адепти цього забобону вбачають помилковість виразу в тому, що вираз я вибачаюсь нібито "філологічно" треба розуміти як я вибачаю себе, а що "вибачати себе" нелогічно і суперечить нормам етики, то форму я вибачаюсь "позбавляють мовних прав", а мовцям не рекомендують або й забороняють її вживати.
>
> Той, хто боронить цей погляд, користується не власною, а позиченою логікою, повторює те, що почув від інших — можливо навіть у процесі навчання — і сприйняв таке пояснення безкритично.
>
> Той же, хто розпочав "цькування" цілком нормального українського слова, переносить неприйняття виразу я извиняюсь росіянами на український ґрунт, заперечуючи правоможність виразу я вибачаюсь і для українців. Таке копіювання чужих стандартів абсолютно хибне.
>
> Стандарти російської мови добрі для росіян, українська ж мова має свої усталені традиції і свій усталений слововжиток.
>
> Звернімось до класиків. Цитую:
>   "Дуже вибачаюсь, що самому ніколи забігти до Вас" (Панас Мирний).
>   "Знала, що даремно образила подругу. Першою думкою було вибачитись" (О. Донченко).
>
> Форма вибачаюсь не може бути русизмом, бо в російській літературі вживання виразу я извиняюсь не зафіксовано. Російські пуристи поборюють цей вжиток саме в середовищі русифікованих українців, які вираз я вибачаюсь переклали на російську мову як я извиняюсь. Якщо для росіян останній вжиток — ляпсус, то про наш вираз я вибачаюсь цього сказати не можна. І про це свідчать цитати з творів письменників.
>
> Але й саме "теоретичне обґрунтування" алогічності виразу я вибачаюсь непереконливе. Твердження, що я вибачаюсь нібито значить я вибачаю себе, само по собі алогічне.
>
> Частку -ся, що творить зворотні дієслова, не завжди можна розуміти як скорочену заміну себе. Коли слова купатися, хреститися тощо і справді можна пояснити як купати себе, хрестити себе, то слова цілуватися, вітатися, молитися й багато інших аж ніяк не значать цілувати себе, вітати себе, молити себе.
>
> Річ у тім, що частка -ся, приєднуючись до дієслів, надає їм не тільки значення зворотньої дії, але й низку інших значень. У словах цілуватися, вітатися частка -ся надає дієслову забарвлення взаємної дії: цілувати один одного, вітати один одного. У слові молитися частка -ся надала слову молити значення молити Бога за себе.
>
> Отже, додача частки -ся до слова вибачати жодною мірою не значить, що слово набуло значення вибачати себе. На ділі слово вибачатися набуло значення просити вибачення для себе.
>
> Тому заперечення логічності виразу я вибачаюсь на тій підставі, що мовець "вибачає сам себе", просто кажучи, "не лізе ні в які ворота".
>
> Оскільки словниками української мови зафіксовано дієслово вибачатись, уживане в літературі і в живій мові, то чому його не можна вживати в усіх можливих граматичних формах: я вибачаюсь, він вибачився, вони вибачаться тощо?
>
> <sub>//Святослав Караванський, [«Пошук українського слова, або боротьба за національне „Я“»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Poshuk_ukrainskoho_slova_abo_borotba_za_natsionalne_Ya/), ст. 89–90, «ХХХ-а. Пуристичні забобони».</sub>

<sub>**Трішки off-topic**

Колись я вишукував вжитки слова «играться» («гратися») в російській літературі. Через те, що деякі російські пуристи відмовляють цьому слову в праві вжитку в певних значеннях, мовляв, правильно «ребёнок играет» («дитина грає»), а не «ребёнок играется» («дитина грається») — і я хотів довести, що це не так. Але я побачив, що слово «играться» в цьому значенні справді було непритаманним російській мові до певного часу (лише в пасивних або безособових зворотах на зразок «свадьба играется» («весілля грається») або «ему не игралось» («йому не гралось»)) — а один із перших вжитків «играться» («гратися») в потрібному значенні в російській літературі — це російське видання «Чорної ради» Пантелеймона Куліша. Хоча з певного часу «играться» («гратися») поширилося і в російській мові. З цього можна зробити висновок, що для української мови справді характерний трішки ширший вжиток форм на *-ся*, ніж для російської (і можливо, це стосується й слів «извиняться»/«вибачатися»).</sub>

Джерело, що навело мене на ширше бачення і статтю Караванського: [стаття «Вибачаюсь чи прошу вибачити?» на сайті творчої групи "Своєрідне Коло»](http://svkolo.org/vybachayus-chy-proshu-vybachyty/).

Answer (score 3):

В принципі, зазначена цитата з Вікіпедії, незважаючи на її заплутаність, здається, відповідає на поставлене питання.

Слово «[вибачатися](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7842&page=291)» в українській мові існує. Наприклад, можна сказати «він вибачився» або «він довго вибачався».

Але використання формулювання «я вибачаюсь/вибачаюся» під час самого прохання вибачити вважається розмовним чи то навіть трішки зухвалим. Мовляв, той, хто має просити про вибачення, формулює своє прохання таким чином (із часткою «-ся»), що може скластися враження, що він не прохає в співбесідника згоди вибачити, а постулює, що його вибачать. Про недолугість форми «я вибачаюсь/вибачаюся» зокрема кажуть [Марія Волощак](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/dieslova), [Євгенія Чак](http://chak-chy-pravylno-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/v#vybachyty), [Борис Рогоза](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/13.htm) і [Борис Антоненко-Давидович](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/vybachatysya-proshhaty-daruvaty-pereproshuvaty).

Чому одне й те саме дієслово можна використовувати для опису процесу прохання про вибачення, але не рекомендується використовувати під час самого процесу? Ну, це можна порівняти з привітанням/поздоровленням. Ми можемо сказати «він привітав/поздоровив когось з днем народження» — але під час самого вітання від того, хто вітає, зазвичай очікують трішки більшого, ніж сухої констатації «я вітаю/поздоровляю тебе з днем народження» (наприклад, щирих побажань абощо). Тобто та фраза, яку цілком можна використовувати при короткому описі процесу, виявляється недостатньою під час самого процесу (хоча у випадку привітання/поздоровлення ситуація менш жорстка — ці слова використовувати хоча б як частину поздоровлення; але вітання/поздоровлення передбачає більш оптимістичний контекст). Коротко кажучи, комусь може видаватися недоречним використання **під час** процесу слів, що зазвичай використовують **для опису** процесу (за умови, що є інші форми, що їх традиційно застосовують саме під час процесу).

<sub>Є й інша позиція, див. [іншу відповідь](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3410).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

В [Довіднику з українського словживання М.Волощак "Неправильно-правильно"](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/dieslova) зазначено 
Неправильно ***"Я вибачаюсь"*** - правильно ***"Вибачте мені"***

Не можна говорити ***"я вибачаюсь"***, тому що зворотна частка `-сь` `(-ся`) означає "себе", тому сказати ***"я вибачаюсь"*** - це рівнозначно ***"я сам собі вибачив".***